# Echo alert in php using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new to the programming world, so take it easy.. I'm running some tests and i realise that when I use jQuery libraries outside of php to create a form, the echo inside the php doesn't work. I actually want an alert message but I found out that this can be done with

```
echo "<script>alert ('message')</script>";
```

but anyway echo is responsible for not seeing anything..
Is the problem the jQuery libraies (which I don't really think so..) or I'm just not knowing what I'm doing..?

What code could I use..?

Thank you in advance..!!

Comment: Show your actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("message")</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it in HTML `script` tags:

```
echo '<script>alert("message");</script>';
```

Comment: They did, but it just wasn't showing up in their code example.

Comment: @BillTurner Then this should work. Except you have replaced the default JS alert with the one from jQuery UI and have not included the UI stylesheets. …or something alike

Answer (score 0):

Probably you execute this code directly by the response from AJAX, or something went wrong with other JS code in your page.

Comment: You propably right.. Im using it under if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

Answer (score 0):

Got it..!! I realise that with jQuery libraries the page refresh too fast after i submit my form and my code runs.. the fast refreshing doesn't leave any time to the alert message to pop-up. So that's it.. When i use my page without jQuery libraries takes a longer time to refresh after i submit and the pop-up.. well pops-up